# AutoIncrement pulando valores

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um código inicialmente de cadastro e login, tudo ok.
Adicionei uma constraint unique nas colunas do banco de dados que não quero que repita e funcionou bem. Porem, queria saber como consigo tratar essa repetição também no código do C#, visto que, se uma pessoa coloca um e-mail duplicado por exemplo, queria que aparecesse a mensagem: "E-mail já cadastrado!".

E outro ponto negativo, como não tratei no C#, quando eu tento inserir um dado repetido, ele realmente não entra no banco, ok. Mas, a ID que está com `auto_increment` pula, ou seja, se estava inserido no banco até a ID 1, tentaram inserir 4 vezes um dado duplicado, o próximo armazenamento no banco vai para ID 5, como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código até o momento está assim:

```
public string Cadastrar(string nome, string email, string senha, string confirmarsenha, string celular, string lembretesenha)
{

    // checar se campos não estão em branco
    if (!email.Equals("") && !senha.Equals("") && !celular.Equals("") && !lembretesenha.Equals(""))
    {
        // checar se senha e email tem caracteres minimos
        if (senha.Length >= 5 && email.Length >= 3)
        {
            // checar se senha é igual a confirmar senha
            if (senha.Equals(confirmarsenha))
            {
                comando.CommandText = "insert into funcionario(nome, email, senha, celular, lembretesenha)values(@nome, @email, @senha, @celular, @lembretesenha);";
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", celular);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lembretesenha", lembretesenha);

                check = false;
                try
                {
                    comando.Connection = conect.Conectar();
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conect.Desconectar();
                    this.mensagem = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";

                    check = true;
                }

                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    this.mensagem = "Erro com o banco de dados!";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("As senhas devem ser iguais!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, use uma senha com mais de 5 caracteres!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, não deixe campos em branco!");
    }
    return mensagem;
}
```

Comment: Seguindo a sua estrutura de Programação. VocÊ poderia criar um método para verificar se o usuário já está cadastrado. Caso ele já esteja você não chamaria as rotinas de cadastro.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar o seguinte método:

```
 public bool VerificarLoginExistente(string login)
    {
        comando.CommandText = "select * from funcionario where email = @login";
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
       
        try
        {
            comando.Connection = conect.Conectar();
            armazenardados = comando.ExecuteReader();

            if (armazenardados.HasRows)
            {
                check = true;
            }
            conect.Desconectar();
            armazenardados.Close();
        }

        catch (SqlException)
        {
            this.mensagem = "Erro com banco de dados!";
        }
        return check;
    }
```

No método do cadastro vocÊ poderia fazer a verificação antes de executar o cadastro:

```
public string Cadastrar(string nome, string email, string senha, string confirmarsenha, string celular, string lembretesenha)
    {

         if(!VerificarLoginExistente(login)){
        // checar se campos não estão em branco
        if (!email.Equals("") && !senha.Equals("") && !celular.Equals("") && !lembretesenha.Equals(""))
        {
            // checar se senha e email tem caracteres minimos
            if (senha.Length >= 5 && email.Length >= 3)
            {
                // checar se senha é igual a confirmar senha
                if (senha.Equals(confirmarsenha))
                {
                    comando.CommandText = "insert into funcionario(nome, email, senha, celular, lembretesenha)values(@nome, @email, @senha, @celular, @lembretesenha);";
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", celular);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lembretesenha", lembretesenha);

                    check = false;
                    try
                    {
                        comando.Connection = conect.Conectar();
                        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conect.Desconectar();
                        this.mensagem = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";

                        check = true;
                    }

                    catch (SqlException)
                    {
                        this.mensagem = "Erro com o banco de dados!";
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("As senhas devem ser iguais!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, use uma senha com mais de 5 caracteres!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, não deixe campos em branco!");
        }
        return mensagem;
    }

   }
}
```

OBS: Não verifiquei se a identação está correta. É só para passar a deixar a ideia mais clara.

Espero ter ajudado.